# How to query distinct values from a projection? - python - google app engine - ndb

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, distinct-values

I get an error when I use

```
qry = models.Amodel.query(models.Amodel.an_id == an_id).fetch(projection=["a_field"], distinct=True)
```

namely this error:

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'distinct'

and all the posts for how to do this are from 2013 and aren't valid anymore.

How do I get unique values from a query with google app engine?

I don't like my hacked solution because it seemingly takes too long:

```
qry = models.Amodel.query(models.Amodel.a_property == a_property).fetch(projection=["a_field"])
return json.dumps(list(set([x.a_field for x in qry])))
```

How do I optimize this, or query for distinct values in the first place?

Comment: @DanCornilescu do you know where the docs might be for it? It mentioned moving the arguments inside the query, just want to see what it looks like. (i.e `query(expression, projection=["a_field"],  distinct=True).fetch()` ?)

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/projectionqueries#Python_Grouping